# Where would custom subscripts be suited over methods/functions and why?

Tags: swift, subscript

I've researched this in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) and am confused on where  custom subscripts are useful compared to methods and functions. What is the power in using them rather than using a method/func?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's purely stylistic. Use a subscript whenever you'd prefer this syntax:

```
myObject[mySubscript] = newValue
```

over this one:

```
myObject.setValue(newValue, forSubscript: mySubscript)
```

Subscripts are more concise and, when used in appropriate situations, clearer in intent.

Comment: So its best to write out a custom subscript when you want to access/alter elements in an array/dictionary but it wouldn't be useful to write a subscript that returns a multiplied number...correct?  Also, can't I write a method or function that access and alters a specific element of an array/dictionary?.....that was my point....what would be the difference? Just the subscript keyword?......and the nonnamed closure?

Comment: Yes, the only difference between a subscript and a method is style and appearance of code. And yes, the best times to use subscripts are accessing/altering child elements of something. If you think of your operation as "looking something up", consider a subscript.

Comment: so basically the `subscript` keyword is just for the sake of organization and the compiler doesn't do any calculation when seeing the `subscript` keyword, its just for me the programmer to organize my code better...?

Comment: All the subscript keyword does is change the syntax you must use when calling your method from `myObject.setValue(newValue, forSubscript: mySubscript)` to `myObject[mySubscript] = newValue`.

Comment: okay, I see.....I really appreacitate your time and effort in helping me with this.....Im more familiar with the power of custom subscripts now, but I believe I might search programs and see them in effect to fully wrap my head around its difference from funcs/methods/closures.....but you helped a great deal, I've been studying this in a swift book but it doesnt really break down the details which is why I'm usually confused.

Answer (score 1):

Which is an easier, clearer way to refer to an array element: `myArray[1]` or `myArray.objectAtIndex(1)`?

Would you like to say`myArray[1...3]`, or would it by just fine if you had to say something like `myArray.sliceFromIndex(1).throughIndex(3)` every time?

And hey, you know what? Arithmetic operators are also just functions. So don't we abandon them, so we'd have to say something like

```
let sum = a.addedTo(b.multipliedBy(c))
```

Wouldn't that be just the same really? What's the power in having arithmetic operators really?